# creating a list from a txt.file

Tags: python

Lets say I have a txt-file that goes something like this:

Yellow 23

Black 44

Red 59

Green 21

I am creating a list from this file according to the following code:

def create_list_from_file(self):

```
    list = []
    for line in self.file:
        data = line.rstrip().split()
        list.append((data[0], data[1]))
```

How do I write color instead of data[0] and number instead of data[1] in the append line?

Comment: `data[0]` is already a string, to convert string `data[1]` to a number, you can use `int(data[1])`.

Comment: *"How do I write color instead of data[0]?"*. Do you mean you want to decode `"Yellow"` into RGB values or what?

Answer (score 0):

Use Python's [Destructuring](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/14981/destructuring-assignment)

#### Old

```py
def create_list_from_file(self):
    list = []
    for line in self.file:
        data = line.rstrip().split()
        list.append((data[0], data[1]))
```

#### New

```py
def create_list_from_file(self):
    list = []
    for line in self.file:
        color, number = line.rstrip().split()
        list.append((color, number))
```